Crocoblock search Filter by year, filter by month
is it possible to create checkbox filter using search filter for year and month, if yes
thanks in advance
their is a date range filter, but it shows in calendar format, which is not good for user experience, so i want to create checkbox filter, but not able to do so.


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
